# como pasar objetos HTML como parametros

Tags: javascript, java, html5, jsp, objetos

queria saber como posso passar uma variável `VARIAVEL` do tipo `"[object HTMLTableRowElement]"` como parâmetro para enviar a um JSP que vai fazer um `$(VARIAVEL).remove()` usando javascript.

Esta variável tem um valor parecido a esse `$(this).parents()`, ou seja, `VARIAVEL = $(this).parents()`;

Comment: Lucas, qual o problema? Não consegui entender qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: como posso pasar essa variavel do tipo [object HTMLTableRowElement] para um jsp

Comment: Você não pode. Passe o ID desse elemento.

Comment: Suspeitei que no podia, mas obrigado.